# Implement JSON response containing the billing token and HTML code

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to implement this payment api (https://developer.vivawallet.com/web-api-integration/native-checkout-v2-api/) ... I just don't know how to handle the response data.

I got recived this in my source:

```
{
    "chargeToken": "ctok_bcGN8H87tGi1qtxtEoYkliYgMrc",
    "redirectToACSForm": "<html><head></head><body>Hey there! Don't
      forget to render me!</body></html>"
}
```

When the **redirectToACSForm** HTML code is rendered, an authentication session is initiated.The user is redirected to  page to authenticate before continuing with the transaction.

The API returns with this error:

```
array(3) {
  ["status"]=>int(400)
  ["message"]=>string(45) "PaymentsCardHolderAuthenticationInvalidStatus"
  ["eventId"]=> string(4) "2061"
}
```

According to [vivawallets](https://developer.vivawallet.com/web-api-integration/error-codes/#rejection-reasons) it's happens because "**Browser closed before authentication finished**"

I'm tring resolve this using PHP!